# How would I format a list of options in restructured text that shall be rendered as man page with Sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, manpage

I'm planning to write the documentation of a command line tool as restructuredtext. I'm using Sphinx to render the docs. Beside the `html` target I want to use the `man` target, in oder to supply docs that can be read in a terminal.

Though I found the relevant configuration variables in the Sphinx documentation, I did not come across hints or example how one would format the documentation sources to achieve a list of options as commonly seen in manual pages as two-column-table.

Are there any guidelines around that cover good practices for `html` *and* `man` targets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option lists are supported in reStructuredText. See http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#option-lists.

This should work for both HTML and manpage output. There is no special directive; you simply create a two-column table, like this:

```
-h, --help      Show help message and exit
--debug         Turn on debug logging
--verbose       Turn on verbose output
```